# How to write a join query in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've a database with the following schema:

**id:** int

**name:** varchar

**email:** varchar

**facebook:** varchar (possible values: Y or N)

**twitter:** varchar (possible values: Y or N)

**time:** timestamp (create timestamp)

We can have multiple rows for the same person where facebook, twitter and time may/will vary.
I want to make a query where I finally want the following:

> **name**
>
> **email**
>
> **total_count** (total number of rows for email)
>
> **total_facebook_yes** (Total number of YES for Facebook for email)
>
> **total_twitter_yes** (Total number of YES for Twitter for email)
>
> **last_time** (The timestamp from the latest row for email)

I'm stuck at writing a query. Can anyone guide me. Please help. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a join query, you need an group with count and max functions.

Something like:

```
select
    name,
    email,
    count(name) as total_count,
    sum(facebook = 'y') as total_facebook_yes,
    sum(case when twitter = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as total_twitter_yes,
    max(time) as last_time
from `table_name`
group by name, email
```

With the limited knowledge about the schema, i would suggest you to look into splitting the table into multiple tables with relations. Have a look at wiki [3th-normal-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) to start with.

Comment: The total_facebook_yes and total_twitter_yes is showing incorrectly. It's showing similar value to count(name).

Comment: I think you should use "sum" instead of count where you use case statements.

Comment: yes, I have updated it for sum, a small glitch until i tested it on a database ;) note I have made two different ways of summing one with case and other with simple comparing, just choose the one strategy you like.

Comment: Yeah, the first way looks easy and sweet! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the expected results, where do you expect the JOIN to take place? Try this. Mysql is forgiving in terms of boolean wrapping,

```
SELECT NAME, EMAIL, COUNT(FACEBOOK='yes') as FBTOTAL_Count, COUNT(Twitter='yes') as TOTALTW_Count
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY FACEBOOK, TWITTER, NAME, EMAIL
```

Comment: I have a typo in my group by line. Wrote from mobile and unable to edit it. Remove facebook, twitter then try.